# something wrong in view page and url

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using c# and ASP.NET MVC4 for a web application (with mobile template).
I'm having a problem with my Details view page. (First you select something from Index page and then it goes to Details page) I have put a bing map on the page and the map doesn't load.
First I thought it was something wrong with the map but its not.
I noticed that the url is 
`http://localhost:2550/Place/Details`
 of the page. However if I manually put a '1' on the end like so `http://localhost:2550/Place/Details/1`
then the map loads on the page. I don't understand why this is...

does anyone know why? thanks

my view page for Details:

```
@model Project.Models.Place
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Details";}
<h2>Place Details</h2>
<fieldset>
<div class="display-label"> Name: @Model.Name</div>
<div class="display-label">Address: @Model.Address</div>
<div class="display-label">Post Code: @Model.PostCode</div>
<div class="display-label"> PhoneNo: @Model.PhoneNo</div>
</fieldset>

<p>    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</p>

<body onload="getMap();">
  <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
  <div>
     <input type="button" value="createWalkingRoute" onclick="createDirections();" />
  </div>
  <div id='directionsItinerary'> </div> 
</body>

@section scripts{

 <script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = null;
      var directionsManager;
      var directionsErrorEventObj;
      var directionsUpdatedEventObj;

      function getMap() {
          map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), { credentials: 'mykey' });
      }

      function createDirectionsManager() {
          var displayMessage;
          if (!directionsManager) {
              directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
              displayMessage = 'Directions Module loaded\n';
              displayMessage += 'Directions Manager loaded';
          }
          alert(displayMessage);
          directionsManager.resetDirections();
          directionsErrorEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsError', function (arg) { alert(arg.message) });
          directionsUpdatedEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function () { alert('Directions updated') });
      }

      function createWalkingRoute() {
          if (!directionsManager) { createDirectionsManager(); }
          directionsManager.resetDirections();
          // Set Route Mode to walking 
          directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.walking });
          var seattleWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Seattle, WA' });
          directionsManager.addWaypoint(seattleWaypoint);
          var redmondWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Redmond, WA', location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.678561, -122.130993) });
          directionsManager.addWaypoint(redmondWaypoint);
          // Set the element in which the itinerary will be rendered
          directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('directionsItinerary') });
          alert('Calculating directions...');
          directionsManager.calculateDirections();
      }

      function createDirections() {
          if (!directionsManager) {
              Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', { callback: createWalkingRoute });
          }
          else {
              createWalkingRoute();
          }
      }
  </script>

}
```

my controller action for Details:

```
    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.events = eventRepository.PlaceEvents(id);
        return View(placeRepository.Find(id));
    }
```

Comment: Please post your Detail action and view!

Answer (score 1):

Possible cause, may be you haven't written Controller default controller with Zero arguments.

Or you haven't written controller with [HttpPost] attribute

Will be easy if you put code for the controller here.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that the navigation with /1 at the end works but your current url is without the number, your url on the index page is wrong. 
Your url is now something like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Place")
```

Change it to something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Place", new { id = @Model.Id })
```

So the problem is that your id isn't given to your details action.

Comment: this is what I have in my Index page that goes to Details page:     @using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Place", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <div class="editor-field">
        Please choose a place: @Html.DropDownList("id",  (SelectList)ViewBag.placeDDL, "Choose...")
        </div>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }

Comment: Why are your posting a form if you want to navigate. Change your code to a hyperlink or handle the onchange javascript event to navigate to the specific page. In that way, you can also use the url to get to that detail page.

Comment: because the details page shows the address etc of selected place, which is chosen from dropdown list

Comment: so would it be better to do as link than a dropdown list?

Comment: ok so I tried using an actionlink instead and it did go to /1 in the url, but now the map doesn't display. this is what I used @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.placeID })

Comment: Ok so it is not the id? You set that it worked when you did /1. Can you edit your question with the controller action?

Comment: LockTar no apparently not, when you go details page from index page the map doesn't load. but If you refresh the page then it loads. weird right? my controller action for details is up there ^

Comment: So when you navigate from the index page to the details page with you adjusted code the map isn't loaded but if you hit F5 (refresh) after navigating, the page does get loaded?

Comment: yes that is right. I have now noticed that this is a problem in the mobile template application of MVC4. If I choose the Internet application template for MVC4 in Visual Studio, then the map loads as it should.

Comment: Maybe the externel javascript libraries are not the same as the mobile template.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by this, can you specify please?

Comment: The external scripts like jQuery, jQuery UI, jQuery Mobiel etc. Maybe that the map tool only work with particulair versions or screensizes? Sorry I don't know anything more.